# Using EF 4 on .NET 3.5 SP1

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

I was using the latest EF 4 bits in Visual Studio 2010 RC and have fallen in love with it.
However, I have to develop a small web application using .NET 3.5 SP1 (VS 2008) for work... I was wondering if it was possible to somehow utilize EF 4 in .NET 3.5 SP1/VS 2008.

Regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EF4 requires .NET 4 (it's part of .NET 4), and you can't use that from a .NET 3.5 application.

Comment: Because of different CLR versions (4.0 and 2.0)

Comment: And SharePoint 2010 is only 3.5 :(