# Using Entity Framework 4.0 in a .Net 3.5 Application

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using EF 4 on .NET 3.5 SP1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500609/using-ef-4-on-net-3-5-sp1)

Is it possible to use Entity Framework v4.0 in a .NET 3.5 application?
I mean, can i just reference the related assemblies for EF 4.0 and use it in my .NET 3.5 application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the EF 4.0 uses the .NET 4.0 framework, which is newer and completely separate from the .NET 3.5 framework.