# Exporting Entity Framework 4 Data Model to Entity Framework 3.5

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Is there a way to export a EF 4.0 Data Model to EF 3.5?

I looked around and found that we are not able to access EF 4.0 from a ASP.Net 3.5 project here: [Using Entity Framework 4.0 in a .Net 3.5 Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876887/using-entity-framework-4-0-in-a-net-3-5-application)

Our project is the 1st to go to .Net 4.0 using Entity Framework and we (the team) were wondering if there was a way for the other projects that "might" need to access our data that are still using the .Net 3.5 framework.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit fiddly, but it can be done. Either manually or with an XSLT, change the `xmlns` of the nodes in the EDMX as well as the version flag.

Easiest way to see what's involved is:

1. Make a new EF 1 model in VS 2008.
2. Back it up.
3. Upgrade it to .NET 4 with VS 2010
4. Diff the two models.

You'll find they're not *that* different, as long as you're not using .NET 4 only features.

Comment: Thank you, we will give that a shot!  I appreciate your input.